# Determination of Normal Subgroups based on Order

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ such that $[G:H] = 3$, then, is $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$?

Answer (score 1):

This is false: Let $G = S_4$ and $H = \langle(1234), (13)\rangle$ as [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group%3aS4).

---

If $G$ has odd order, the answer is yes.

Comment: I don't immediately see why order of $G$ being odd implies $H\unlhd G$.. Could you please elaborate a bit or give some hint...

Comment: More generally, if H has index p, where p is the smallest prime dividing the order of G, then H is normal in G.  Look at the action of G on the left cosets of H by left multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

No, but $H$ contains a normal subgroup of $G$ with the index $3$ or $6$.